# flags in highcharts are getting misplaced

Tags: highcharts, angular5, angular2-highcharts

When we are giving dynamic continuous data flags are going misplaced and interupting ther graph please help in this and i also want the flags should get diaapear when the latest flag arrives

[image: As shown in the image of highcharts i have done]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8c6mw5vf/ forgot to add fiddle in this fiddle we are using chart.redraw i think for that issue the chart is showing multiple flags please help me here

Comment: Please do not provide a link to the code, include a [mcve] in your question. Thank you.

Comment: The demo you've posted doesn't have any flags. Could you share a better one? Could you describe your problem more precisely?

Comment: when i am giving random data in the demo there is no problem but when i am giving the data from back end the problem arriving

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unable to tell you anything without some live demo or code with your app.